# How can I solve in python to work my subpage?

Tags: python, html, django

I would like to call another html file (Magamrol.html) from another, but this happens when I am trying to open:

> 

Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
[name='index']
admin/
polls/
```

The current path, Magamrol.html, didn’t match any of these.

My app is polls and the project name is mysite.
The mysite\polls\urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from polls import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('', views.magamrol, name='Magamrol')
    
]
```

mysite\polls\views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Üdvözöllek a honlapomon!")

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def magamrol(request):
    return render(request, 'Magamrol.html')
```

mysite\urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from polls import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index,name="index"), 
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('polls.urls'))      
    
]
```

Does anyone know how can be solved this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you expect the empty string in `path('', views.magamrol, name='Magamrol')` to match `'Magamrol.html'`?

Answer (score 1):

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('', views.magamrol, name='Magamrol')
    
]
```

you have to change one the url path name like:

```
path('magamrol/', views.magamrol, name='Magamrol')
```

when you use two same end point it can be create conflict.

Comment: Thank you! I have changed, but this error occured:

Comment: AttributeError: module 'polls.views' has no attribute 'magamrol'

Comment: Has been solved! in polls.views I have been adding this: def magamrol(request):
    return render(request, 'Magamrol.html') Thank you!